# How to change values in json with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON data structure which looks like this (as I'm just a beginner, right now I have it in my HTML code, so it is not a separate JSON file.

```
var udalost = {
  "typ_udalosti": "ples",
  "stoly": [
{
  "idStola": 1,
  "pocetMiest": 6,
  "miesta": [
    {
      "idMiesta": 1,
      "meno": "Janko Hrasko",
      "datum": "13.8.2016",
      "stav": "rezervovany"
    },
    {
      "idMiesta": 2,
      "meno": "",
      "datum": "",
      "stav": "volny"
    },
    {
      "idMiesta": 3,
      "meno": "",
      "datum": "",
      "stav": "volny"
    },
  ]
},
{
  "idStola": 2,
  "pocetMiest": 4,
  "miesta": [
    {
      "idMiesta": 7,
      "meno": "",
      "datum": "",
      "stav": "volny"
    },
    {
      "idMiesta": 8,
      "meno": "Juraj Meliska",
      "datum": "16.8.2016",
      "stav": "zaplateny"
    }
   ]
  },
 ]
}
```

I have also a form with textarea:

```
<form id="Rezervacia">
        <div class="container">
           <label><b>Meno Priezvisko:</b></label>  
           <input type="text" id="meno" minlength="5" placeholder="Zadaj meno" name="user" required ><br>
           <button id="k1" type="submit" >Rezervovat</button>
           <button type="button" id="cancelbtn" >X</button> 
       </div>
</form>
```

What I want is that, when a user puts any text (in my case it should be name) into the textarea and then presses the submit button I want to save it to the JSON file. But what is important, I have a variable: `kliknuteMiest` which is saved as `idMiesta`.

So it means when `var kliknuteMiest = 2` and the user put "Joe Bar" into text area, I want to my JSON to look like this:

```
 {
  "idMiesta": 2,
  "meno": "Joe Bar",
  "datum": "",
  "stav": "volny"
 },
```

Variable `kliknuteMiest` is always a different number, so I want to do it in general not just for number 2. I was trying something like this but as am beginner it is not working:

```
$('#k1').click(function(){ 
   for(var stol of udalost.stoly){              
     for(var miesto of stol.miesta){
        if(miesto.idMiesta == kliknuteMiest){
            miesto.meno = $('#meno').val();     
        }
     }
   }    
});
```

Comment: Actually what you have is an object structure which you want to save to a JSON file. JSON is just a format, like CSV or DOC which specifies how data should be structured.

Comment: You want to store it temporarily or permanently?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no I dont have a separate JSON file ....I have a variable in my html code in which I have data in JSON format

Comment: @Fantasterei permanently

Comment: @Jane you can't store data via javascript. Onliest way is to send the data to an server-side script language like php or so.